# Symfony2: Fatal error: Interface 'Knp\Menu\Matcher\Voter\VoterInterface' not found in

Tags: php, symfony, twitter-bootstrap, composer-php

I wanted to integrate twitter-bootstrap in my Symfony2 project and trying to make it work, I followed documentation is [BootstrapBundle](https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/1-installation.md).
After installing all dependencies set in `composer.json`, i get this error:

> Fatal error: Interface 'Knp\Menu\Matcher\Voter\VoterInterface' not found in /var/www/cv-  editor/vendor/mopa/bootstrap-sandbox-bundle/Mopa/Bundle/BootstrapSandboxBundle/Navbar/Example/Voter/RequestVoter.php on line 12

Have you any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

After debvugging, i found that there is a problem in dependencies of MopaBootsrapBundle which works with Knp-menu-bundle version 1.2